# How to allow 6to4 through iptables firewall?

Tags: debian, iptables, ipv6

Im trying to allow 6to4 though my ipv4 firewall on Debian 6 (Squeeze) but without much luck, it seems most of the syntax used by other OS's isn't quite supported in Debian's iptables.

I'v tried: (I put these before the DROP all INPUT/OUTPUT lines)

```
$IPT -A INPUT -p ipv6 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p ipv6 -j ACCEPT
```

Along with a few others but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using 6to4, you do not transmit IPv6 packets.  Instead, special IPv4 packets are wrapped around IPv6 payloads.  These packets have IPv4 protocol 41, as defined by RFC 2473.

```
iptables -t filter -I INPUT -p 41 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -I OUTPUT -p 41 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: ^ the -t filter doesn't seem to be supported by Debian 6 "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name." iptables v1.4.8

Comment: @Mint: No, the `filter` table always exists.  I misspelled the chains `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` though; those should be upper-case.

Comment: aah I see, I'm new to iptables so it's not so obvious to me. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: Just a small note: `-p 41` is equal to `-p ipv6`. At least, this is what `ip{,6}tables-save` produces.