# How can I stop my VPS from dropping incoming IPv6 tunnel traffic?

Tags: debian, ipv6

I have a Hurricane Electric tunnel set up on my Debian Squeeze Xen VPS. It seems to work half the time, and drop incoming traffic to the tunnel half the time. I did what [this question's](https://serverfault.com/questions/234840/how-to-allow-6to4-through-iptables-firewall) answer said, but to no avail: it still seems to intermittently stop accepting traffic. When I ping it when it's not accepting the traffic it gives me a "Destination host unreachable" error, so it could simply be a routing issue that's on HE's end, but I don't know.

Comment: Is your VPS behind a NAT?

Comment: It shouldn't be; I have a static public IP assigned and no private IP assigned as far as I can tell.

Comment: There goes that idea. I use SixXS for all my tunneling needs, and their setup is a bit different. I can suggest that you ask Hurricane Electric to help; they are supposedly very good at this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

If the host is behind a stateful firewall the firewall might drop the traffic if the state times out. Creating a cron job on the host that sends a ping (or something like that) to an outside host every few minutes might keep the state in the firewall fresh.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have more than 1 ethernet interface, you don't have accidentally configured two gateways? If so it can cause intermittent connection problems with the tunnel, remove the gateway you're not supposed to use. Regular IPv4 traffic may work fine if it's allowed to go through either gateway.